# How make np.roll working faster for one dimension array?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I generate a two zero arrays by np.zero then i use np.roll to make circshifting array. But when i calling np.roll in cycle it works very slow. Is there any way to speed up my code?
Here is the code:

```
        preamble_length = 256
        threshold_level = 100
        sample_rate = 750e3
        decimation_factor = 6

         preamble_combination = [1,-1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1,-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1,  -1, 1, 1,1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1,1]

        sequence = np.zeros(preamble_length)
        buffer_filter = np.zeros(preamble_length)
        size_array = sample_rate / decimation_factor
        
        rxDataReal = np.real(downsample(rxData, decimation_factor)) #rxData is a array of complex numbers
    
        rxDataDownSampled = rxDataReal
        check = 0
        find_max = 0
        peak_max = 0
        preamble_ready = 0
        received_flag = False
        size_array = int(size_array)
        main_counter = 0

        #In this section the np.roll working very slow
        for main_counter in range(size_array):
            if(preamble_ready == 0):
                if(rxDataDownSampled[main_counter] < 0):
                    check_sign = 1
                else:
                    check_sign = -1
    
                sequence = np.roll(sequence, -1)#this
                buffer_filter = np.roll(buffer_filter, -1)#and this
                sequence[preamble_length-1] = check_sign
                bufferSum = sequence * preamble_combination
                buffer_filter[preamble_length-1] = np.sum(bufferSum)
                find_max = np.max(buffer_filter)
    
    
                if(find_max >= threshold_level):
                    peak_max = find_max
                    sequence = np.zeros(preamble_ready)
                    buffer_filter = np.zeros(preamble_length)
                    print('Value of peak_max: ', peak_max)
                    received_flag = True
    
                if(received_flag==True):
                    break
        preamble_value = peak_max
```

Comment: Do you need `roll()` at all? Can you accomplish the same thing just by indexing into the array differently? e.g. this `buffer_filter[preamble_length-1] = np.sum(bufferSum)` could avoid the roll by using a different index each time. Or this `bufferSum = sequence * preamble_combination` looks like a convolution, which can be done faster by using `np.convolve()` to compute all the convolutions at once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [numba.jit can’t compile np.roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61011294/numba-jit-can-t-compile-np-roll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `roll` are doing:

```
In [118]: x=np.arange(10)
In [119]: np.roll(x,-1)
Out[119]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

You can look at the `np.roll` code; it's probably more general, it has to, in one way or other, copy all the values of `x` to a new array.  This might be a bit faster, since it doesn't try to be as general:

```
In [120]: y=np.zeros_like(x)
     ...: y[:-1] = x[1:]; y[-1] = x[0]
In [121]: y
Out[121]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

### times

Nope, it isn't faster:

```
In [122]: x=np.arange(100000)

In [123]: timeit np.roll(x,-1)
82.1 µs ± 102 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [124]: %%timeit 
     ...: y=np.zeros_like(x)
     ...: y[:-1] = x[1:]; y[-1] = x[0]
     ...: 
     ...: 
93.4 µs ± 4.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

other timings:

```
In [128]: timeit y=x[1:].copy()
52.4 µs ± 164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [129]: timeit np.concatenate((x[1:],x[0:1]))
58.6 µs ± 289 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```